# Why setBackgroundMessageHandler not working in iOS?

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am using React native free-base version v10. 1 and React native firebase messaging version 14.9.1. I got the notification in the background but was not able to get logs(payload) in iOS. is there any solution for this. **Note: Without the open notifications, only get logs in background mode.**

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I am also facing the same issue on iOS. On Android it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

try using this instead of `setBackgroundMessageHandler`

```
messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp((notification) => {
  console.log('Background Notification', JSON.stringify(notification));
  // Handle Your notification here
});
```

Comment: without open notification only on get background mode @Bhavya Koshiya

Comment: it's seems to be currently not working in iOS i spent days finding it and got nothing

Answer (score 0):

On ios, first build your app in configuration release.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand, setBackgroundMessageHandler is a Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) method to handle notifications when the app is in the background state. However, this method only works on Android, not on iOS. This is a limitation of FCM on iOS, because this operating system has a different and stricter way of managing background running than Android.

You can use a third-party library to support background notification processing on iOS, such as Notifee. Notifee is a library designed to work with FCM, allowing you to create versatile and customizable notifications on both Android and iOS. You can use Notifee's onBackgroundEvent method to handle notification-related events when the app is in the background state.